# Installing Imagemagick using Homebrew does not give me the imagemagick command

Tags: homebrew

Hello I am trying to use homebrew to install Imagemagick and I use the following command:

```bsh
brew install imagemagick
```

The installation finishes with no error and I do get the folder: `/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/`.
But the command is not added to my terminal environment and I cannot find the commandline tools binaries. I have the bin folder in the Cellar folder for imagemagick but not the `convert` and so on binaries.
Am I missing something?

I am running the newest update of macOS Catalina if that is relevant.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11865600/3487310) and see if this helps.  Also, have you reviewed the support and community questions on the Homebrew site?

Comment: The pkg-config part should not be need :/

Comment: And the installation should work the first time, too, but you never know....I get that it's an older question but there's several answers provided there.  In addition, the Homebrew site probably sees this kind of issue more often than we do so that's your first choice for support issues.

Comment: It’s important to reference the documentation:  https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php

Comment: I miss wrote I don't have any of the commands

Comment: Please run `brew doctor` and resolve any issues found. If it still doesn't work, edit the question and add the output of `echo $PATH` and `ls /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/*/bin`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `imagemagick` command. `/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/` is the Homebrew folder containing the content of the package. To see the names of the installed commands run

```
$ ls /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/*/bin
Magick++-config     compare         display         magick-script
MagickCore-config   composite       identify        mogrify
MagickWand-config   conjure         import          montage
animate             convert         magick          stream
```